# Possible to change element name upon transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <File>
    <Id>123</Id>
    <Created>21/12/2013</Created>
  </File>
  <Employee>
    <Personal>
      <Name>Juan Dela Cruz</Name>
      <Age>27</Age>
      <Address>
        <Street1>Street1</Street1>
        <Street2>Street2</Street2>
        <PostalCode>123456</PostalCode>
      </Address>
    </Personal>
    <Employment>
      <DateHired>21/12/2013</DateHired>
      <Position>Clerk</Position>
      <EmploymentType>Contractual</EmploymentType>
      <Department>Sales</Department>
    </Employment>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Personal>
      <Name>Juana Change</Name>
      <Age>28</Age>
      <Address>
        <Street1>Street1</Street1>
        <Street2>Street2</Street2>
        <PostalCode>123456</PostalCode>
      </Address>
    </Personal>
    <Employment>
      <DateHired>22/12/2013</DateHired>
      <Position>Manager</Position>
      <EmploymentType>Full-Time</EmploymentType>
      <Department>Sales</Department>
    </Employment>
  </Employee>
</Document>
```

Which I need to transform into something like this:

```
<Profiles>
  <File>
    <FileId>123</FileId>
    <FileDate>21/12/2013</FileDate>
  </File>
  <EmployeeProfile>
    <Information>
      <EmpName>Juan Dela Cruz</EmpName>
      <Age>27</Age>
      <EmpAddress>Street1 Street2, 123456</EmpAddress>
      <EmpStartDate>21/12/2013</EmpStartDate>
      <EmpPosition>Clerk</EmpPosition>
      <EmpType>Contractual</EmpType>
      <EmpDepartment>Sales</EmpDepartment>
    </Information>
  </EmployeeProfile>
  <EmployeeProfile>
    <Information>
      <EmpName>Juana Change</EmpName>
      <Age>28</Age>
      <EmpAddress>Street1 Street2, 123456</EmpAddress>
      <EmpStartDate>22/12/2013</EmpStartDate>
      <EmpPosition>Manager</EmpPosition>
      <EmpType>Full-Time</EmpType>
      <EmpDepartment>Sales</EmpDepartment>
    </Information>
  </EmployeeProfile>
</Profiles>
```

Is there a way for mew to do this using XSLT, because the source XML is from a different format than the format I wanted it to have.

Please let me know and thanks in Advance

- Edited

Comment: Yes. This type of transformation is the whole point of XSL.  However, if you've never written an XSL transform, StackOverflow is not the place to come and receive a complete solution.  You will need to invest some time in learning to write XSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial stylesheet to get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Document">
        <Profiles>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </Profiles>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="File">
        <File>
            <FileId><xsl:value-of select="Id"/></FileId>
            <FileDate><xsl:value-of select="Created"/></FileDate>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <Information>
            <EmpName><xsl:value-of select="Personal/Name"/></EmpName>
            <Age><xsl:value-of select="Personal/Age"/></Age>
            .
            .
            .
        </Information>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key to understanding this is to realize how the XSL processor works.  The stylesheet is not a "program" in the traditional sense.  It is a set of rules that get applied as the processor reads your XML.  It takes some getting used to but when you "get" it the beauty of XSL will become apparent.

Comment: If I have multiple <EmployeeProfile> how can I make it refer to each employee profile, because I am always getting the first profile and I dont get the value of the next one.

Comment: Based on the _input_ structure I don't see how you can have multiple EmployeeProfile sections per Document.  You'll have to edit your example to show what the input looks like for multiple EmployeeProfile output sections.

Comment: You've changed the structure of the output significantly.  I've updated the example. I strongly suggest you go through some XSL tutorials and try to understand my example code so you can modify and maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a push-type stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


    <!-- This is called an identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Document">
        <EmployeeProfile>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </EmployeeProfile>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="File">
        <Profile>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Profile>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="File/Id">
        <ProfileId>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ProfileId>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="File/Created">
        <ProfileDate>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ProfileDate>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <Information>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Information>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Personal|Employment">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Personal/Name">
        <EmpName>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </EmpName>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Personal/Address">
        <EmpAddress>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </EmpAddress>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employment/DateHired">
        <EmpStartDate>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </EmpStartDate>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employment/Position">
        <EmpPosition>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </EmpPosition>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employment/EmploymentType">
        <EmpType>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </EmpType>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employment/Department">
        <EmpDepartment>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </EmpDepartment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it the simple way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Profiles>
        <File>
            <FileId><xsl:value-of select="Document/File/Id"/></FileId>
            <FileDate><xsl:value-of select="Document/File/Created"/></FileDate>
        </File>
        <xsl:for-each select="Document/Employee">
            <EmployeeProfile>
                <Information>
                    <EmpName><xsl:value-of select="Personal/Name"/></EmpName>
                    <Age><xsl:value-of select="Personal/Age"/></Age>
                    <EmpAddress>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Personal/Address/Street1"/>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Personal/Address/Street2"/>
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Personal/Address/PostalCode"/>
                    </EmpAddress>
                    <EmpStartDate><xsl:value-of select="Employment/DateHired"/></EmpStartDate>
                    <EmpPosition><xsl:value-of select="Employment/Position"/></EmpPosition>
                    <EmpType><xsl:value-of select="Employment/EmploymentType"/></EmpType>
                    <EmpDepartment><xsl:value-of select="Employment/Department"/></EmpDepartment>
                </Information>
            </EmployeeProfile>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Profiles>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```